# Is there a method for outputting a single row into single column where original column name and value will alternate?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, testing

I am white box testing a single row for a wide table on our database (something we do for pretty much every large development).

So we do a simple select by the primary key:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTAB WHERE MYKEY = 42;
```

This yields a large number of columns (for the sake of this example, let's say 26 - **please don't get hung up on the data, this is purely for example**).

```
Alpha . . . Zulu
-----       ----
237902      RABBIT

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Is there a way of outputting such so that each column gets it's own output so:

```
Alpha
-----
237902

(1 row(s) affected)
.
.
.
Zulu
----
RABBIT

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Or where each column is forced onto the next line so:

```
Alpha
-----
237902
.
.
.
Zulu
----
RABBIT

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @Amadan  `each column gets it's own output` **UNPIVOT** will give you one output.

Comment: Search `dynamic PIVOT` or `dynamic UNPIVOT` to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use power of Dynamic SQL:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376566)**

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(
   ID   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Name VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,Age INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #tab(ID,Name, Age) VALUES (1,'John', 14), (2,'Jane', 23);
INSERT INTO #tab(ID,Name, Age) VALUES (3,'Joe', 34),  (4,'Jimmy', 54);

DECLARE 
  @col_name   NVARCHAR(128) = NULL,
  @table_name NVARCHAR(128) = '#tab',
  @counter    INT           = 1,
  @id         INT           = 1,
  @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
INTO #columns
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @table_name + '%';

WHILE @counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #columns)
BEGIN

  SELECT @col_name = COLUMN_NAME
  FROM #columns
  WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @counter;

  SET @sql += 
  N'
  SELECT <col_name>
  FROM <table_name>
  WHERE ID = @id';

  SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<col_name>', @col_name);
  SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<table_name>', @table_name);

  SET @counter += 1;
END

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
      @sql
      ,N'@id INT'
      ,@id;
```

Output:

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╠════╣
║  1 ║
╚════╝

╔══════╗
║ Name ║
╠══════╣
║ John ║
╚══════╝

╔═════╗
║ Age ║
╠═════╣
║  14 ║
╚═════╝
```

*Warning:*

Sample table is from my previous example, but I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @RobbieDee Great to hear :)

Comment: @RobbieDee I slightly modify code (shortened it) for clarity.